# the console isnt printing the array in my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I  am beginner in JavaScript and I'm trying to log an array, but in the console, it shows me something different.
here is the code:

```js
var cars = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Porsche"];
console.log(cars);
```

and here is what is see in the console:

```
Array(3)
0: "Ferrari"
1: "Lamborghini"
2: "Porsche"
length: 3
```

Why isnt it printing the whole array but printing these things? help please.
thanks

```
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: ?? That looks like the whole array to me. What exactly did you expect?

Comment: For me your example outputs, `[
  "Ferrari",
  "Lamborghini",
  "Porsche"
]` in the browser. In the console I see what you posted, however I'm not clear on what it is that you expect to see

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: As above, think of an array as an object with numerical keys. It's printing it as expected.

Comment: are you using internet explorer or old edge?

Comment: so probably the error is from my side, sorry for bothering

Comment: @DanielA.White google chrome, the ide is vscode and i am using live server

Comment: It's not an error. It's showing you it's an array with three indexes.